# Want to stop Caching in CS CART (Multivendor)

Tags: cs-cart

I want to stop caching in CS-CART (mainly for API), because if vendor changes something then in api it didn't reflect immediately.

Right now i am using File level caching.

```
$config['cache_backend'] = 'file';
$config['cache_redis_server'] = 'localhost';
$config['cache_redis_global_ttl'] = 0;
```

I searched a lot but no success, i also tried with

`$config['smarty_caching'] = 0 ;`

in config.php but also no success.

Answer (score 1):

from cs cart [reference](https://docs.cs-cart.com/latest/developer_guide/getting_started/configuring_cscart.html)

Disable PHP block caching

```
$config['tweaks']['disable_block_cache'] = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no ability to disable cache at all. You are only able to disable block cache for the frontend.

> if vendor changes something then in api it didn't reflect immediately.
>   Cache should be invalidated immediately.

What's your CS-Cart version?